# Is it possible to alter database password of MS-Access database using ucanaccess?

Tags: ucanaccess

Was trying to unset database password of MS-Access database using ucanaccess.

But it gives error like :

UCAExc:::5.0.1 java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token: DATABASE in statement [ALTER DATABASE PASSWORD **** *****;]

Can you let me know how to alter database password of MS-Access using ucanaccess in jdk8.